# Symfony 5 Mailer embedded images with liip imagine_filter

Tags: symfony, symfony5, liipimaginebundle, symfony-mailer

In a Symfony 5 project E-Mails are created using the Mailer components TemplatedEmail() function.
In the used twig template ($templatedEmail->htmlTemplate(..)) an image is embedded using

```
<img src="{{ email.image('@v_images/user-'~user.id~'/v.jpg') }}">
```

to include a user-specific image.
This works fine.
When trying to pass that image to liip filters by

```
<img src="{{ email.image('@v_images/user-'~user.id~'/v.jpg') | imagine_filter('v_watermark') }}">
```

the image deosn't render anymore.
I was thinking about the resolver settings to be applied to make liip able to read from the non-standard target path - but didn't find any sensible setting.
Documentation didn't lead me to any helpfull information.
For any hints on how to make liip work with Mailer embedded images would help me a lot.

**EDIT** (thanks @ArleighHix):

I also tried nesting the filter inside the call like

```
<img src="{{ email.image('@v_images/user-'~user.id~'/v.jpg' | imagine_filter('v_watermark')) }}">
```

which resulted in the following error:

```
Unable to find template "@v_images/user-1https:/127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/resolve/v_watermark/v.jpg" (looked into: [SENSIBLE_LOCAL_PATH_IN_PROJECT]).
```

I am unsure what exactly happens but the path seems to be concatenated weirdly...

Comment: Have you tried nesting the filter inside the call to `email.image`? Like `email.image( ('path')|imagine_filter('v_watermark') )`

Comment: I did now - resulting in this error: Unable to find template "@v_images/user-1https:/127.0.0.1:8000/media/cache/resolve/v_watermark/v.jpg" (looked into: [SENSIBLE_LOCAL_PATH_IN_PROJECT]). I am unsure what exactly happens but the path seems to be concatenated weirdly...

Comment: Add exactly what you tried to the question along with the error it produced, I'll upvote maybe someone else knows.

Comment: Why not trying to use ``asset()`` https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#asset to get the image path ? Couple it with the ``imagine_filter`` https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#example

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE I think asset only returns public pathes. The image used here is from a non public path and therefore embedded in the email. I could be wrong regrding the public pathes only thing thought...

Comment: @user3440145 You're right ! So combine it with absolut_url https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-link-to-assets (watch "If you need absolute URLs for assets...").

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#absolute-url documentation

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE Using absolute_url() on asset() doesn't change the need for the asset to be stored in a public place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [absolute_url()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#absolute-url) combine with [asset()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#reference-twig-function-asset).

Base on this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-link-to-assets)

> If you need absolute URLs for assets, use the absolute_url() Twig

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('images/logo.png')) }}" alt="Symfony!"/>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ absolute_url('favicon.png') }}">
```

### Solution 1

I think this one should work :

```
<img src="{{ email.image((absolute_url(asset('@v_images')) ~ /user-'~user.id~'/v.jpg) | imagine_filter('v_watermark')) }}">
```

### Solution 2

If it don't work, you should add a gloabl variable with base url.

twig.yaml

```
twig:
  globals:
    app_base_url: '127.0.0.1:8000' // Put your base url here
```

And use it as :

```
<img src="{{ email.image(app_base_url ~ asset('@v_images') ~ /user-'~user.id~'/v.jpg) | imagine_filter('v_watermark')) }}">
```

Of course as you'll publish your website on the web, the base_url would change.
You may use a service parameter `'%app.base_url%'`

Define it in you configuration files :

services_dev.yaml

```
parameters:
   app.base_url: 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/'
```

services_prod.yaml

```
parameters:
   app.base_url: 'https://your.website.url/'
```

And then update your twig.yaml as

```
twig:
  globals:
    app_base_url: '%app.base_url%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. However using absolute_url() on asset() doesn't change the need for the asset to be stored in a public place - which in my case is not an option.